# PIL rendering on raspberry pi different than custom OS

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, raspberry-pi3, yocto

I am having an issue with PIL (python image library). Same code running on standard raspbian and the same on custom Yocto OS don't have the same output. The yocto one is deformed, especially the `0` character

I am using python 2.7 and PIL 1.1.7.

I tested increasing `gpu_mem to 128Mb` on the yocto, use `vc4graphics` but this is not changing anything. I guess there's something I don't think about as I'm inexperienced with image rendering.

I would like to understand how to debug this.

**Raspbian:**

[image]

**Custom Yocto:**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are too many assumptions to say anything definitely.
Are both systems using same graphical backend?
If not, you should probably match them.
It's not "Yocto OS", it's usual Linux, Yocto is just a tool to improve work-flow of building Linux.
What LCD are you using?
Usually when you are developing for board, with some new model of lcd, you also get a datasheet from vendor to tweak different parameters. I had the same problem with display not being crisp, look for lcd display section of .dts file. There should be parameters like "bits-per-pixel", which you should match to what is advised in a data-sheet.
In your case since you have 2 systems with one having a clear image and one having a fuzzy one, I can advice to look for .dts file on both systems and match lcd sections for them. Just an example of a path to .dts file in Yocto

```
build/tmp/work-shared/imx6ulevk/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts
```

Find .dts files for both systems, look for what's different in lcd display section and copy raspbian lcd parameters to your Yocto .dts file.

Comment: As I never mentioned, I tried the same backend, didn't work. As I didn't mention, I'm not using an LCD, it is the `show` command from PIL giving this output.